# Creating a 301 redirect with regEx till forward slash

Tags: regex, redirect

I'm rebuilding a website and changing a CMS. Former CMS had weird URL structure - it was adding post id in the end of the URL with forward slash. For example:

```
www.mydomain/category/someurl/54
```

I'd like to create 301 redirects in .htaccess with regex for a new CMS (WordPress). How could I create a pattern that would just simply match old CMS URL to new URL by removing last forward slash and id in URL?

Basically it should be like this:

```
301, from www.mydomain/category/someurl/54 to www.mydomain/category/someurl
```

Comment: Something like `RewriteRule ^(.*)/\d+$ $1 [R=301]` if you are using mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

You can place this rule as **very first rule** just below `RewriteEngine` line.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/[^/]+/?$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Glad to know it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.